# How to write to a file from frontend?

Tags: javascript, file, io, frontend

How does draw.io write to a local file just from my browser without me having any server app or browser extension for it? I'm talking not about the file download feature, but about literal writing to a file. So when I create a new diagram, it prompts me to save a file, and then whenever I make a change to the diagram, the file gets updated.

Comment: They probably use the FileSystem API, which can be used on any modern browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem You can take a look at the code of the webapp at https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/tree/dev/src/main/webapp

Answer (score -1):

There are various of browser local storage, you can put your data there instead store to server.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage